# VB.NET Key Capture on TextBox to run different SUB

Tags: vb.net

What I am trying to do is when user enters value in textbox and press `ENTER` ,  wait for another input between `ENTER` and `*`. if he keys in `ENTER` do something and if he keys in `*` do something else.

Textinput>`ENTER` KEY>`ENTER` KEY>SUB1()

Textinput>`ENTER` KEY>`*` KEY>SUB2()

I am not able to wraparound best possible way to execute this.

Thank you

Comment: what ways you got so far?

Comment: What kind of application is this?  WinForms?  Is "TextInput" a **TextBox** or something else?  Have you considered using a Multi-Line input?  What if they enter something followed by `*` and hit enter, but never entered anything before that?  Should `Sub2()` run if `Sub1()` was never executed?  Should `Sub1()` run immediately?...or only be run before `Sub2()` when a command followed by `*` is entered.  Details, details, details...

Comment: @Idle_Mind Its WinForms and yes textinput is in TextBox. So  for First Enter it will check if thats a valid product code, once its valid the user can press another Enter to add the product to sales grid view, and if he wish to edit the content he will press *. I am trying to replicate a VB6 application which the then developer did something like the above I mentioned.

Comment: @Fabio I got to the level of first Enter with this code 'If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then SUB3()    e.Handled = True End If', is there a way I could send the focus to some thing else which will capture next KeyUp Event, I am trying to replicate a VB6 application which the then developer did something like the above I mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not ~quite~ sure I'm following, but maybe something like below will get you to where you need to be.

Label1 is letting the user know if what they type is valid or invalid when they hit enter.  If valid and enter is hit again, then it is added to ListBox1 (a grid in your case).  Once an entry is made, if they hit "*", then it will go into "editing" mode.  If they type anything else, then everything is reset and typing "*" would do nothing.

```
Private EntryAdded As Boolean = False
Private ValidEntryMade As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Label1.Text = ""
    ValidEntryMade = False
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        If Not ValidEntryMade Then
            ValidEntryMade = IsValid(TextBox1.Text)
            Label1.Text = If(ValidEntryMade, "Valid", "Invalid")
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Clear()
            ValidEntryMade = False
            EntryAdded = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If EntryAdded AndAlso e.KeyChar = "*" Then
        e.Handled = True
        TextBox1.Clear()
        MessageBox.Show("Editing")
    End If
    EntryAdded = False
End Sub

Private Function IsValid(ByVal entry As String) As Boolean
    ' ... however you do this ...
    Return (entry.Length = 6)
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome, you just showed me the way how to go about with this example Thank you so much for the help :)